# Read lines from a text file, reverse the sentence and save in a new text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, file-handling

```
 f = open("text.txt", "rb")
 s = f.readlines()
 f.close()
 f = open("newtext.txt", "wb")
 f.writelines(s[::-1])
 f.close()
```

my orignal text file is

```
Hi ashmi
```

it show output

```
Hi ashmi
```

but i want output

```
ashmi Hi
```

Comment: `readlines()` returns a list of all the lines present in the given file. And in this case, list has only one element, so even after reversing, the list will remain same.

Comment: Kindly accept one of the answers if it solves your question. If you require clarifications or changes in detail, add that as a comment to them.

Answer (score 2):

This works there is probably a better way but regardless here it is.

```
f = open("text.txt", "r")
s = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("newtext.txt", "w+")
for i in s:
    word_list = i.split()
for i in word_list.__reversed__():
    f.writelines(i+' ')

f.close()
```

what i have done is split the words in the text file into a new list then used the reversed function to reverse the list then save the words to a new text file.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now this reverse order of words in a sentence and not letters in a word

```
f = open("text.txt", "rb")
s = f.read()
f.close()
s = s.split()[::-1]
f = open("newtext.txt", "wb")
f.writelines([b" ".join(s)])
f.close()
```

here is an alternative

```
f = open("text.txt", "rb")
s = f.read()
f.close()
s = s.split()[::-1]
f = open("newtext.txt", "wb")
f.write(b" ".join(s))
f.close()
```

Comment: oh you dont want letters in word to be reversed then Wait!